# Product of limsup

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f(x)$ be positive and increasing and $g(x)$ satisfy $\limsup_x g(x)=1$.

I want to show $\limsup_x f(x) g(x)=\infty$

Is that true and how do i show it?

I'm thinking that since $f(x)$ is monotone and increasing $\limsup _x f(x)=\lim _n f(a_n)$ for any $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ where $a_n\to \infty$

Since the second limsup exist I also (think I) know that i can find a sequence such that $\limsup _x f(x)=\lim _n f(a_n)$.

I got the feeling this is the right way to go, but how do I conclude?

Edit: okay, $\lim_x f(x)=\infty$ i forgot that wasn't true from the given. Is the statement true now?

Comment: Your hypothesis on $g$ says that infinitely often, $g(n) > 1/2$ and your hypothesis on $f$ says that for each $N > 0$ there is an $n$ such that $f(n) > N$.  Try to combine these.

Comment: @louis from where do you have $f(n)>N$, i don't get them

Comment: @dom: Good point.  If $f$ is increasing but bounded, the statement is wrong.  (So the desired conclusion makes sense only when there's a typo in the question.)

Comment: Yes, it's true now.  What is $\lim_n \bigl[ f(a_n)g(a_n)\bigr]$?

Comment: Well.. If both limits exist it would just be the product of the limits. Is that true still?

Comment: You can show that the limit is $\infty$. See Louis' comment. (But, yes, it is true that the limit of the product is the product of the limits if the latter limits exist and at least one is finite.)

Comment: Oh yea, that is actually pretty easy to show. Sometimes ones brain just doesn't work properly in math.. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I didn't missunterstood your question,
 taking $f(x)=\arctan(x)+\pi$ and $g(x)=1$ should be a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Another trivial example if the question is stated correctly: $$f(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\quad\text{and}\quad g(x)=1.$$ Then $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)=\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x)=2<\infty.$$

Comment: yes I guess the question is really about behavior near $+\infty$ so my comment above was irrelevant, and I'll remove it.